# Php syntax ( if or )

Tags: php, html, css, sql, syntax

Sorry i really can't test this by myself!
Are they correct?

```
   if ($var1 == "example" or $var2 == "example2") {
    }
```

or

```
     if (($var1 == 1) or ($var2 == 2))
```

Thanks (sorry for mistakes, italian).

Comment: why can't you test it actually..?

Comment: They are both correct. The extra parens `()` are not needed in this case.

Comment: Use codepad.org (http://codepad.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is correct and both version are equivalent in terms of logic.

I would write it like this:

```
if ($var1 == "example" || $var2 == "example") {
  ...
}
```

Although `or` is [perfectly valid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if ($var1 == "example" or $var2 == "example") {
  ...
}
```

You are asking if it is needed to enclose in parenthesis. It is not, while it can be useful if your condition grows enough to make it difficult to understand when one starts and the other begins.

Comment: `$var2` is checked if it is "example2"

Comment: What do you mean, @Reza ?

Comment: Well the question is like `if ($var1 == "example" or $var2 == "example2")`!

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants to know if the parentheses within the conditions are needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the syntax

```
if ($var1 == "example" || $var2 == "example2") {}
```

Comment: Why its doesn't work? `if ($var1 == "example" or $var2 == "example2") {}` . Can you explain?

Comment: or is also valid, but I would write like this.